# Does 'Excel' in 'Excel.Application' refer to an Object? If not, what does it refer to?

Tags: excel, vba, object

I am trying to understand the hierarchy of object classes in VBA, and I can't understand why one has to write Excel.Application rather than just Excel, eg why do we have to write Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook rather than just Excel.ActiveWorkbook?

It would make sense to me if 'Excel' denoted an object in a class called something like 'Office App' whose other members were Word, Access etc, and objects of that class had a number of methods and properties, of which Application was only one. But I can't find any such class in Microsoft's online reference and, as far as I can tell, Application is the only property or method name that can go after the dot after the word Excel.

Is it just an idiosyncrasy of how VBA was set up, or is there some internal logic as to why VBA requires us to write Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook rather than just Excel.ActiveWorkbook?

The same question applies to all the other MS Office apps, eg why we have to write Word.Application.ActiveDocument rather than just Word.ActiveDocument.

Thank you

Comment: The Automation Standard says applications should have Application object. Document based programs should have a Document object. Note Application object's properties and methods are global. Also Applications and Document objects must support certain methods and should support others if relevant. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/using-the-application-object-in-a-type-library. So `PROGRAM.OBJECT`.

Comment: `Excel` is referred to as a `NameSpace` which you will understand better once you develop an application that uses Excel as an Interop or COM object in something like Visual Studio. A NameSpace usually has a main Application object that holds the structures relative to that NameSpace. It's a little different in VBA as if you are already in Excel, the NameSpace is assumed, so you can just use `Application.ActiveDocument` instead of `Excel.Application.ActiveDocument` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia

Comment: `ActiveDocument` is a property that returns a `document` object. Remember open apps and documents also register themselves in the Running Object Table (ROT).

Comment: @braX Thanks for the info about Namespace. I hadn't come across that concept before. In code, does one ever write Excel.<something that is not Application>? If so, what would an example be. If not, I wonder why we need to write Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook rather than just Excel.ActiveWorkbook. ie treat Excel as an object, of which ActiveWorkbook is a property.

Comment: @Mark. Thanks for the info about the ROT. I expected there to be some such form of registration. So I was surprised when my code in a MS Word VBA module that used ActiveWorkbook returned no result, even though an Excel workbook was open at the time. Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook also gave no result. I ended up having to use the GetObject function to make the MS Word VBA aware that Excel was running, so that ActiveWorkbook became non-empty (I needed the workbook ref to copy data from excel to a Word table). Is it supposed to work that way? Perhaps I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Often times there is more than one way to do things because there is an "old way" that still needs to be supported after they come out with a "better way"

Comment: `CreateObject` creates a new object - for Word that is a new Word started with the `/a` switch. `GetObject(FName)` tries to connect to a document object in the ROT, and if not open opens the file in the default application in both cases returning a document object. `GetObject( , "Word.Application")` (note omitted first parameter) tries to connect to a application object in the ROT and fails if Word is not open. `CreateObject(FName)` returns a NEW document object.

Comment: To answer your question in your title. Excel is in the registry as `Excel.Application`, `Excel.Sheet` etc (there's charts and other stuff). The format standard is `ApplicationName.Object` and the object is often the `application` object so `Excel.Application`. The last line above should be _`CreateObject("Word.Document")` returns a NEW document object_